# What does "brother mine" mean?

Tags: grammar

What exactly does "brother mine" mean? Is it the same as "my brother"?

As far as I know "brother" is a noun and "mine" is a pronoun, so it doesn't make much sense to me why one can precede the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means "my brother".

It's an archaic formation; once standard English, but now only used poetically, especially in a few stock phrases (of which "brother mine" is perhaps the most common).

Comparably, to use *mine* in this sense before the noun is also archaic and now only used poetically, especially in a few stock phrases, of which "mine host" is perhaps the most common.

Comment: Related to "brother of (o') mine"?

Comment: @Jon Hanna - the example of 'mine host' you mention is an example of what used to be a standard - albeit archaic now - use of 'mine' rather than 'my' before an 'h' or a vowel sound, eg 'Mine eyes have seen the glory of the coming of the Lord'.

Comment: @d'alar'cop no, in Old English "[noun] mine" was perfectly standard, and as late as when Shakespeare used "For doating, not for louing, pupill mine" it was still perfectly normal. It later mostly died out, but there is no elided *of*.

Comment: @LeonConrad and that in turn a retention of what used to be a standard use of *mine* before any noun, e.g. "At that daye shall ye axe in myne name." from Tyndale's translation of John 16:26, it just lasted longer before vowels due to being particularly euphonious in such positions.

Comment: @JonHanna - thanks for pointing that out - I hadn't thought about it! Love making new connections.

Comment: @Leon: I believe that the standard use of "mine" wasn't before an 'h' or vowel; it was just before a vowel sound. However, 'host' used to be pronounced 'ost'. Shakespeare used *"a heart"* but *"an host"*: *"Well, nobles, well, 'tis politicly done,
To send me packing with an host of men."*

Comment: @PeterShor as long as you don't have an host who finds it pretentious.

Comment: Would _mine eyes_ not be more common than _mine host_? I don't think I've ever used the latter, but “Do mine eyes/ears deceive me?” is relatively common, even in colloquial speech.

Comment: Is the first use of this from The Tempest act five when Prospero says "you brother mine ..."

Comment: @AaronH.Alpern that's not even the first use of it in Shakespeare's works, and it goes back to before the Modern English he wrote in.

Comment: @AaronH.Alpern indeed I quote a use of it by Tyndale in a comment above, and he died a couple of decades before Shakespeare was born, though it certainly didn't originate with him either.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a contraction of 'brother [of] mine'.

Comment: Could be a throwback to Latin - frater meus?... also maybe German - mein Brueder?

Comment: You could think of it that way, but why not just learn that it was once used and now mostly isn't? Thinking of it as a contraction serves the would-be expert poorly, because it's incorrect, and the novice just as poorly as it would lead them to use the formation freely when it should be reserved for cases where archaic formations work better (i.e. almost never).

Comment: @d'alar'cop it would be related to *mein Brueder*, in that it's cognate with it and both *mein* and *mine* share a common root, but it goes back to the very beginnings of English, and only died out in the modern period.

Comment: It would be more directly related to (also archaic) _Bruder mein_, anyway. Of the Germanic languages, Icelandic, Faeroese, and Norwegian still use the _X mine_ construction regularly—it is archaic and/or poetic everywhere else.

Comment: Brother of Mine means that he is one of my brothers. While he is my brother may imply that he is my only brother.

Comment: It's very unlikely that it relates to any German languages, German `mein` literally translates to English `my`, whereas English `mine` most closely translates to the German `meins`. In Dutch, there isn't even a word for `mine`.

Comment: @Pelle ten Cate
"It's very unlikely that it relates to any German languages"
That's nonsense. Please explain what you are trying to say there, it doesn't make any sense this way. Both, mine and my are of course related words in the English language.
And mine means in German: meiner, meine, meines, meinen, meins, ... As German is a highly inflected language there is no "closest". And those are all kind of variations of "mein" – English for "my".
And now take a look at Old English... surprise surprise...
I'm not sure you do even know both English and German share a common West Germanic root.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: as already pointed out, the construction *"of mine - of yours - of + ...'s"* translates the partitive genitive, namely it means "X is part of Y". In the example at hand, especially, "brother mine" does NOT mean a member of the collection of all my brothers.